# Greensock TimelineMax callbacks not called

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I have a TimeLineMax sequence defined thus

```
var tl=new TimelineMax({paused: true});

    tl.append(TweenMax.to(f, _flipSpeed, {rotationY: 90 + _offset, visible: false,  onComplete:doneRotateF,ease:Linear.easeNone}))

    tl.append(TweenMax.to(b, 0, {alpha: 1, immediateRender: false}))

    tl.append(TweenMax.to(b, _flipSpeed, {rotationY: 0, onComplete:doneRotateB, ease:Linear.easeNone}));
```

When I call it using

```
tl.tweenTo(_tl.duration());
```

the callbacks work, are called, but when I try to reverse it

```
tl.tweenTo(0);
```

the tweens work but the callbacks are NOT called. What gives?

Comment: Look at the GreenSock Docs for **[tweenTo](http://api.greensock.com/as/com/greensock/TimelineMax.html#tweenTo())** Remember, this method simply creates a TweenLite instance that pauses the timeline and then tweens the time() of the timeline. So you can store a reference to that tween if you want, and you can kill() it anytime. Also note that tweenTo() does NOT affect the timeline's reversed state. So if your timeline is oriented normally (not reversed) and you tween to a time/label that precedes the current time, it will appear to go backwards but the reversed state will not change to true.

Comment: Already answered in the duplicate GreenSock forums post: http://forums.greensock.com/topic/9266-timelinemax-callbacks-not-called/#entry37402

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using just Tweenmax with callbacks . It ended up being less code since with TimeLineMax when I reversed it I needed to change the callbacks slightly, necessitating an entirely new TimeLineMax instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for reverse you should use another callback - `onReverseComplete`

> **onReverseComplete** : Function - A function that should be called when the tween has reached its beginning again from the reverse direction. For example, if reverse() is called the tween will move back towards its beginning and when its time reaches 0, onReverseComplete will be called. This can also happen if the tween is placed in a TimelineLite or TimelineMax instance that gets reversed and plays the tween backwards to (or past) the beginning.